# Erro ao usar uma dll c++ em um código C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

Criei uma dll com um código em C++, quando fui usar deu um erro.

função dentro da dll que eu tentei usar

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void ClickLeftMouse(int x, int y){
POINT cursorPos;
cursorPos.x = x;
cursorPos.y = y;
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, (LPCWSTR)"PXG Client");
DWORD dw = MAKEWORD(cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, dw);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, dw);}
```

como eu declarei a função que está dentro da dll, já no código c#.

```
[DllImport("MouseEvent.dll")]
public static extern void ClickLeftMouse(int x, int y);
```

como eu chamo a função

```
private void checkBox_bother_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClickLeftMouse(546, 16);
}
```

Quando eu click para usar a função da o seguinte erro, alguém pode me ajudar?
[image: Print do erro]

Comment: Essa dll foi adiciona nas referências do seu projeto? Menu Project > Add Reference...

Comment: Acabei de colocar e continua dando o mesmo erro. Pensava que era só por a dll na pasta do projeto..

Comment: Ele não deve estar reconhecendo o path. Dá uma olhada neste post SOen  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864673/specify-the-search-path-for-dllimport-in-net

Comment: Também não deu..